# how to close chrome browser popup dialog using selenium webdriver and python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python code that uses selenium webdriver (along with chromedriver), to log into facebook and take a screenshot of the page.
the script itself works as expected, however, after logging in, chrome browser shows a dialog regarding facebook notifications ([Chrome Popup](http://screencast.com/t/dUtCXk41gvu))

The dialog seems to be generated by the browser, not the page itself.
i'm unable to identify and capture the element or use "switch to alert" method.

How can i interact with this dialog (either Allow, Dismiss or close it)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

in Python you can use

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(path, 'chromedriver'),
                 chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with launching the chrome browser with disabled pop-ups (browser pop-ups). The following code snippet is in Java. It will be somewhat similar in python i believe.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("test-type");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in Python selenium:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=chrome_options)
```