# Click a button in an Instagram pop-up using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I used the following code to login to Instagram with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

time.sleep(1)

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
username.send_keys('username')

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
password.send_keys('password')

time.sleep(1)

loginbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div')
loginbutton.click()

time.sleep(7)

notnow = driver.find_element_by_class_name("yWX7d") 
notnow.click()

time.sleep(3)
```

Everything works but Instagram asks for save login using a pop-up. How do I press the "Not now" button in the pop-up?. I have tried using `xpath` without success.

Comment: Try with disable pop up in selenium from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345066/how-to-close-chrome-browser-popup-dialog-using-selenium-webdriver-and-python)

Comment: Not working. That is only for chrome pop-ups. I am asking for pop ups from instagram. Whenever you login instagram it asks whether to save the login info in a popup. There are two buttons. Save login or Not now. I want to click Not now button

Answer (score 0):

Try to send `Esc` to the page or to this pop up.

`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`
`webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()`

or

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('pop_up_xpath').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)`

Comment: Escape doesnt do anything. Thank you I figured it out. I increased the sleep duration and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]").click()
```